# A subset of a Borel Set is Borel

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Consider:
$$S \subset S^*$$

I'd like to prove that $S$ is a Borel set up to a set of measure zero. I know $S$ is a set of full measure and $S^*$ is a Borel set. The logic in the video (linked below) proceeds as follows:

> $S$ is full measure, thus $S^*$ is full measure, which implies $S$ is Borel up to measure zero set.

I'm confused because:

1. In order to know $S$ is a set of full measure, it needs to be in the sigma-algebra associated with Leb measure. So why did he need the bigger set $S^*$ which is Borel? If you are a set of full measure with respect to Leb measure, aren't you automatically a Borel set?
2. In his explanation, he says the compliment of $S^*$ is a set of zero measure so the compliment of $S$ is a set of zero measure. This is only true if $S^*-S$ (the compliment of $S$ in $S^*$) has zero measure, right?

[Video Link at relevant time](https://youtu.be/sos-wEdR5M0?list=PLo4jXE-LdDTR2kMFp5LnyQ7paxU6hadUK&t=3871)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $S$ is full measure and $S \subseteq S^*$, then necessary $S^*$ is also set of full measure: if $\mu(\overline{S^*}) \leqslant \mu(\overline{S}) = 0$. And also $S$ is full measure in $S^*$: $\mu(S^* \setminus S) \leqslant \mu(\overline{S}) = 0$. So $S$ is a Borel set $S^*$ up to set of zero measure $S^* \setminus S$.

It's not clear why we need $S^*$ here - we can just take the whole space $X$ (that is Borel) instead.

And no, not all full measure sets are Borel. Take any zero set $T$ that is Lebesgue measurable but not Borel - then $\overline{T}$ has full measure, but is not Borel.

Comment: +1. And to the OP, to see why such a $T$ exists: how many Borel sets are there, and how many subsets of the Cantor set are there?

Comment: okay I see that the compliment of $S$ in $S^*$ is measure $0$. How is $S$ Borel?

Comment: @NoahSchweber In more detail then: Borel sets form a sigma algebra. Choose a $T$, defined above, not in the Borel sigma algebra. $T$ compliement will not land in the Borel sigma algebra (otherwise this would lead to a contradiction). Is this correct?

Comment: $S$ isn't necessary Borel, it's Borel *up to measure zero*. For $T$ - you need $T$ not only not to be from Borel $\sigma$ algebra, but also it have measure zero.

Comment: Okay more specifically: suppose $R$ is a set of measure $0$ in $S^*$. Why is $S-R$ Borel?

Comment: $S - R$ doesn't have to be Borel, why do you think it is?

Comment: Isn't that what the statement "Borel up to a set of measure zero" means?

Comment: No. "Borel set up to a set of measure zero" means that union (or, more generally, symmetric difference) of our set with some set of measure zero (not necessary Borel itself) is Borel.

Comment: aha! okay so in this case $S^* - S$ is measure $0$ and its union with $S$ gives is $S^*$ which we assumed to be Borel. correct?

Comment: Yes, it's correct.